# conditional breakpoint on an indirect addressing mode in gdb

Tags: gdb

I would like to set up a conditional breakpoint on an instruction that is like `add [ebp+0xc], 1` but I can't figure out the right expression to give to gdb's shell.

I've tried that one yet it doesn't seem to work:

`b *0xdeadbeef if ($ebp+0x0c) == 0xf00`

But I think it only breaks when $ebp = 0xf0c (0xf00 + 0x0c) and this is not the intented result.

How could I perform a conditional breakpoint in that the memory location pointed by [ebp+0x0c] contains any specific value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
b *0xdeadbeef if *(int*)($ebp+0x0c) == 0xf00
```